# Increase Swap file size that already exists (EC 2 linux)

Tags: swap

I created swap file doing this:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=4096
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

I would like to increase to 16GB

I tried running this command

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=16384
```

but got error:

```
/bin/dd: failed to open ‘/var/swap.1’: Text file busy
```

How would I increase swap file size?

Answer (score 2):

First do `sudo /sbin/swapoff /var/swap.1`, then run `dd` and `mkswap` and `swapon` as you did before.